# How can i change the Inspector.EditorType associated with an Outlook Mailitem?

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-office

In my code, I first display and edit an Outlook Mailitem using the Word Inspector:

```
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set oMail = OutlApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(TemplatePath & TemplateName)

oMail.Display

Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
Set WordDoc = oMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
```

Then I'm doing some manipulation using WordDoc, like adding entries into Tables etc.
After this, I want to close the WordEditor and open the Item in a normal Outlook.Inspector

of course `oMail.GetInspector.EditorType = olEditorHTML` doesn't work because EditorType is a read only property. But however I try to display Mail, the `EditorType` stays `olEditorWord`, and I see no easy way to change it.

Is it possible to change the `EditorType` associated to an `Outlook.Mailitem` without saving and reopening it?

Comment: which office are you on?

Comment: Office 365 32 Bit